# Creating an accurate gravity for Java

Tags: java

I have a view that is 600 pixels in height with 12 boxes, each 50 pixels by 50 pixels. I created a ball where the user clicks that falls based on gravity. I am doing this for a physics demonstration and I am trying to have it as accurate as possible. Currently, the scale that I am working with uses four boxes (or 200 pixels) as one meter. The method that calculates the "y" position gets called 50 times per second (50 fps). When I try to run the program with this code in it, it is off by a decent amount of time.

This is the method that I am calling to update the position:

```
public double calcY()
{
    velocity += acceleration*200/2500;
    return(getY()-velocity);
}
```

I'm multiplying by 200 to convert meters to pixels.
And dividing by 2500 because it's getting called 50 times per second so (50)^2 is 2500.

Right now it's not off by a lot.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: What's your reason for taking the square of the update-rate? I doubt that this is necessary.

Comment: `v = v0 + a*t` (there is no t^2). It's also odd to see `getY() - velocity` .. normally the same `y = y0 + v*t` would be employed (t^2 comes in when combining these two equations). Also, often the *actual* elapsed time is used and not the expected elapsed time.

Comment: also, are you sure your update-function is called 50 times per second? Is there maybe a bug in your timing code? A typical beginners mistake is to forget to account for the time it takes to execute the update-function itself.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculations should never be tied to a fixed frame rate, *measure* the real time that has expired. FPS can and will vary greatly by factors outside your control.

You can keep track of time expired between calls to calcY() using System.currentTimeMillis() - that might be off a few ms between two calls, but it will be pretty precise across multiple calls.

Also last time I checked fall acceleration wasn't one meter per second, but 9.81 m/s. So your calculated acceleration seems to be off by a factor of 9.81.

Edit: Looking at your formula again, it makes no sense to me.

Comment: Measuring the time expired lets you calculate the correct motion for the time between two frames (you know the time expired in between). This allows you to calculate the proper motin for that time. *Fixed* rate has no place in a method that is called at varying rate, like screen updates always are.

Comment: Gravity on Earth results in acceleration of 9.8m/s^2.  In other places, like Mars, or in a simulator, the acceleration might be slower or faster.

Comment: Sure, but I havent been to Mars lately. Any time someone says *gravity* without specifying where I am biased to assume *earth*. Maybe I'm earth chauvinistic :)

Answer (score 0):

You should start with kinematic equation of motion.

```
x = x0 + v0*t + 1/2*a*t^2
```

Acceleration times time squared has the units of position. Here the t, is the absolute time. If you want to compute the position time by frame.

```
v = v0 + a*dt
x = x0 + v0*dt + 1/2*a*dt^2
```

Here at each time you compute the final position and velocity and use that as the initial position and velocity of next frame.

Comment: I changed my code to the following: 'return(getY() - (0.5*acceleration*200*Math.pow((System.currentTimeMillios()-millis)/1000,2)));' I got this from the the equation x = x0 + v0*dt + 1/2*a*dt^2, where initial velocity is 0, and x0 is getY(). I divided the difference in the milliseconds by 1000 to get seconds. The acceleration in this case is "9.8" and I am multiplying by 200 to convert it to pixels. The variable "millis" is the time since it has started falling. However, when I ran this, the ball fell almost twice as fast as it should have. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you updating the getY() each time it is called? The initial position should remain constant through the entire time since x = x0 + v0*dt + 1/2*a*dt^2 computes the absolute position. Make sure the value returned by getY() never changes during each call to calcY().